# I want to use a idiom or phrase that describe the emotion or gesture

Tags: word-choice

I want to use an idiom or phrase that describes the emotion or gesture when people go silent with a finger on their lips when they see something totally bizarre or unexpected?  Thank you

Comment: You might have better luck with the english folks.

Comment: As the previous comments have stated, this question is better suited to English.SE, so I'm going to migrate it there.

Comment: I'd expect a 'deformed fist', knuckles upright, thumb pressed on lower lip and crook of index finger pressed to upper, to show astonishment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about describing both a gesture and a state of mind. I don't know that there's a single word or phrase for what you described. However, you can describe what the character is thinking, feeling or doing. You can do all three, or focus on one aspect. Here are some ideas that might be helpful:

She paused, contemplating the situation.

She appeared deep in thought, a finger pressed to her lips.

He looked hard at the painting, his finger touching his lips, forehead creased.

Michael adopted a "thinker's" face -- index finger at his lips, eyes looking far away.

Their father seemed to be calculating, with eyes half-closed, his left index finger slowly tapping his lips.